# It is redirecting to the same file

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-blade

Can someone tell me what is wrong is this file?
It is redirecting to the same page when I click the submit button and it is not  going to forward. It worked well earlier.

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\guest\forms;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\guest\hirer\HirerForm4;
use App\Models\guest\Loan;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Hirer_4Controller extends Controller
{
    public function storeForm4(Request $request)
    {

        $validated = $request->validate([
            'hirer_nic' => 'required',

            'h_monthly_income' => 'required',
            'h_annual_income' => 'required',
            'h_anticipated_income',

            'h_incomeTax_year1',
            'h_incomeTax_assessable1',
            'h_incomeTax_taxable1',
            'h_incomeTax_tax1',

            'h_incomeTax_year2',
            'h_incomeTax_assessable2',
            'h_incomeTax_taxable2',
            'h_incomeTax_tax2',
        ]);
        dd('5');

        if ($validated);

        // user inputting nic capturing
        $hirer_nic_input = $request->hirer_nic;
        // checking the both nics are matched or not
        $hirer_nic_exsist = DB::table('loans')->where('hirer_nic', $hirer_nic_input)->first();
        // gettin gth elast loan_id from the table
        $last_loan_id = Loan::orderBy('loan_id', 'desc')->first()->loan_id;


        if (!$hirer_nic_exsist) {

            // if both nics are not matched
            return back();
        } elseif ($hirer_nic_exsist) {
            // if both nics are matched

            HirerForm4::create([
                'loan_id' => $last_loan_id,
                'hirer_nic' => $request->hirer_nic,

                'monthly_income' => $request->monthly_income,
                'annual_income' => $request->annual_income,
                'anticipated_income' => $request->anticipated_income,

                'incomeTax_year1' => $request->incomeTax_year1,
                'incomeTax_assessable1' => $request->incomeTax_assessable1,
                'incomeTax_taxable1' => $request->incomeTax_taxable1,
                'incomeTax_tax1' => $request->incomeTax_tax1,

                'incomeTax_year2' => $request->incomeTax_year2,
                'incomeTax_assessable2' => $request->incomeTax_assessable2,
                'incomeTax_taxable2' => $request->incomeTax_taxable2,
                'incomeTax_tax2' => $request->incomeTax_tax2,

            ]);
            return redirect()->route('start.hirerForm-5');
        }
    }
}
```

**Blade**

```
@extends('layouts.dash')

@section('content')
    {{-- form1 --}}

    {{-- <div class="container"> --}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
    <div class="card col mx-5 my-5 border">
        <h5 class="card-header">{{ __('Form 4 - Hirer Personal Details') }}</h5>
        <div class="card-body">

            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('store.hirerForm-4') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf

                <div class="row">
                    {{-- monthly income --}}
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label><b>
                                <h6>21. Total monthly income </h6>
                            </b></label>
                        <input type="number"
                            class="form-control border-info border-2 mb-2 @error('monthly_income') is-invalid @enderror"
                            name="monthly_income" placeholder="Enter the state">
                        @error('monthly_income')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    {{-- annual income --}}
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label><b>
                                <h6>22. Total Annual income</h6>
                            </b></label>
                        <input type="number"
                            class="form-control border-info border-2 mb-2 @error('annual_income') is-invalid @enderror"
                            name="annual_income" placeholder="Enter the state">
                        @error('annual_income')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{-- anticipated income --}}
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label><b>
                            <h6>23. Anticipated income(if any) from Vehical/ Machinery to be purchased</h6>
                        </b>
                    </label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control border-info border-2 mb-2" name="anticipated_income"
                        placeholder="Enter the state">
                </div>

                {{-- income taxes --}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label><b>
                            <h6>24. Income Tax for the pass two years </h6>
                        </b></label>
                    <table style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>
                                        <h6>Year:</h6>
                                    </b></td>
                                <td><b>
                                        <h6>Assessable:</h6>
                                    </b></td>
                                <td><b>
                                        <h6>Taxable:</h6>
                                    </b></td>
                                <td><b>
                                        <h6>Tax:</h6>
                                    </b></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="number" name="incomeTax_year1"
                                        class="form-control border-info border-2 mb-2" placeholder="">
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="incomeTax_assessable1"
                                        class="form-control border-info border-2 mb-2" placeholder=""></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="incomeTax_taxable1"
                                        class="form-control border-info border-2 mb-2" placeholder=""></td>
                                <td><input type="number" name="incomeTax_tax1"
                                        class="form-control border-info border-2 mb-2" placeholder="">
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="number" name="incomeTax_year2"
                                        class="form-control border-info border-2 mb-2" placeholder="">
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="incomeTax_assessable2"
                                        class="form-control border-info border-2 mb-2" placeholder=""></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="incomeTax_taxable2"
                                        class="form-control border-info border-2 mb-2" placeholder=""></td>
                                <td><input type="number" name="incomeTax_tax2"
                                        class="form-control border-info border-2 mb-2" placeholder="">
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>


                {{-- hirer_nic --}}
                <div class="form-group py-3 border-2 border-top border-bottom">
                    <label class="form-label" for="hirer_nic"><b>
                            Enter hirer's NIC or Driving License <span style="color:#ff0000">*</span>
                        </b></label>
                    <input type="text" id="hirer_nic"
                        class="form-control border-primary border-2 @error('hirer_nic') is-invalid @enderror"
                        name="hirer_nic" value="{{ old('hirer_nic') }}" autocomplete="hirer_nic" autofocus>

                    @error('hirer_nic')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>


                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Next</button>

            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
    {{-- </div> --}}


    {{-- form ends --}}
@endsection
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('hirer/1/h/4', [HirerFormController::class, 'startForm_4'])->name('start.hirerForm-4');

Route::post('hirer/store/h/4', [Hirer_4Controller::class, 'storeForm4'])->name('store.hirerForm-4');
```

I am grateful if anyone solves this for me, and I am open to any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll write it here:

Looks like the problem occurred due to validation, there is an input that does not pass validation so it returns to the previous page (in your case it returns to the same page)

Try temporary removing the validation code then see if it works or not